# Why different color between skimage.io.imsave and opencv.VideoWriter

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I'm trying to make opencv VideoWriter to generate avi from images modified by skimage-kit. And I encountered color difference between skimage.io.imsave and VideoWriter.write".

When I see the movie generated by opencv,it looks having only blue. However, if I save the frame by skimage.io.imsave, the jpg file has correct colors.
I assume normalization happens in skimage causes something bad to me but I'm not sure how I can convert them to collect color for opencv.

Can anyone advice why the difference comes from and how I should solve it?
I really appreciate any advice.

[result of imsave,which I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxku.jpg)
[result of output.avi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wafU0.png)

```
import numpy
import cv2
from colorizer import Colorizer  #returns modified 224*224 color image using skimage kit
import skimage

c=Colorizer()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 12.0, (224,224))
i=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cframe=c.colorize(frame)
    #it outputs correct color image
    skimage.io.imsave("result/%d.jpg" % i, cframe)

    #it outputs wrong color
    out.write(skimage.img_as_ubyte(cframe))
    i=i+1
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: There is problem in the color convention code, the first case accepts the format you are giving that is `BGR` I guess but in the second line you need to pass `RGB` image explicitly. So search a way for converting BGR image to RGB or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks ZdaR, I will try with your advice!

Comment: img=np.zeros((224,224,3),dtype=np.float32)
    img[:,:,0]=cframe[:,:,2]
    img[:,:,1]=cframe[:,:,1]
    img[:,:,2]=cframe[:,:,0]
    out.write((img*225.0).astype('u1'))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ZdaR. With your advice, I simply transpose matrix RGB to BGR, then it worked!
Higher version of opencv may have cvcolor RGB2BGR but my enviroment doesn't support it thus I implement in legacy way..

```
cframe=c.colorize(frame)
img=np.zeros((224,224,3),dtype=np.float32)
img[:,:,0]=cframe[:,:,2]
img[:,:,1]=cframe[:,:,1]
img[:,:,2]=cframe[:,:,0]
out.write((img*225.0).astype('u1'))
```

Comment: Instead of 3 steps, you can do it with numpy, as follows: `img = numpy.flip(cframe, axis=2)`. Additionally this can be done in-place when there is memory constraints `cframe = numpy.flip(cframe, axis=2)`